# only use one field if multiple exist - mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am making an album listing, and information in the database is the song title, artist title, album title, and the URL of the album artwork.

I am at a complete dead end, because I've never been successful at attempting to do the following:

If there are multiple songs with the same album, just use one of the album names and continue to the next one.

What I am planning on doing is filling a table with the artwork, album name, and artist. Then it would show the next album, and so on. Here's an example:

```
<td><center><img width="150" src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51Ey1zeerzL.jpg"><br><strong>The Wall</strong><br>Pink Floyd</center></font></a></td>

<td><center><img width="150" src="http://stcmjfpp1312.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/led-zeppelin-mothership.jpg"><br><strong>Mothership</strong><br>Led Zeppelin</center></td>

<td><center><img width="150" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/NRNArt/Slightly-Stoopid--Top-Of-The-World.jpg"><br><strong>Top of the World</strong><br>Slightly Stoopid</center></td>
```

My MySQL table:

```
    mysql> DESCRIBE musicinfo;
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| auto     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | 
| file     | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| artist   | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| album    | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| song     | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| albumurl | varchar(500)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| username | varchar(150)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
| filesize | varchar(9999) | YES  |     | NULL    |                | 
+----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

So I wouldn't want multiple copies of the same album to show up. Hope someone understands and would be able to at least give me some tips.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give some idea how your data is structured and also what your current SQL query looks like?

Comment: Edited with my table structure, and I have no SQL query atm because I have no idea in what direction I'm supposed to go in :(

Comment: You should stop right here and change your schema, splitting into at least two tables, Song and Album. (And probably User.) You have redundant information stored which is almost always a sign of a bad design. You'll run into tons of problems going forward if you don't redesign.

Comment: I've been using this table with multiple scripts and the data came out fine. I'm not worried about it at this time, but thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not experienced with MySQL specifically, but try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    albums.albumurl
    ,albums.album
    ,(SELECT song FROM musicinfo WHERE album = albums.album ORDER BY song ASC LIMIT 0,1) AS firstsong
FROM musicinfo AS albums
```

`(SELECT song FROM musicinfo WHERE album = albums.album ORDER BY song ASC LIMIT 0,1)` is a subquery that will select the first song in the album in alphabetical order.

I'm really hoping MySQL allows aliases on table names.

Comment: I don't know if my English is just bad at this time of day or what, but I was asking to retrieve the album name only once, until the multiples have ceased to exist, then continue to the next album name.

Comment: That is also what I'm trying to achieve.  Did you try my SQL code above?

Comment: Just tried it, and man I love ya! Got the album name only once and also the artwork URL!

Comment: Glad to help.  Does the query make sense now?  Do you have any questions?

Comment: Yes, I read the link that @tomahim included in his answer and I understand why it worked and how. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: I've actually shortened it to `SELECT DISTINCT albums.albumurl, albums.album, albums.artist FROM musicinfo AS albums` which gives me the URL and album name, exactly what I need! 

Cannot thank you enough lol

Answer (score 2):

Simple hack on MYSQL's internal prperty `GROUP BY`

> SELECT * FROM songs GROUP BY album_title

This will generate a table of songs with different album_title and which song is displayed corresponding to a album_title depends on MYSQL table indexing(B+Tree) and all.

Property of `GROUP BY` - If there are multiple copies of group by it combines them into a single one and allows you to work on aggregate values too

> SELECT *,count(*) as numsongs FROM songs GROUP BY album_title

This will give you the number of songs in each album

Comment: This is much cleaner, yet with coge.soft's example, I only get the fields I need. Appreciate the help but I'll stick with his answer :)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to display just one song per album you have to change your SQL query which is execute when your page is loading.

You can use for example the DISTINCT statement : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: My English isn't great, but what I am trying to do is list each album on a page. Each row in my table is a song, and so if I had a while loop running for each row, then it would list multiple albums (because multiple songs in one album). I am trying to just list one album, skip the rest of them, and continue to the next one.

Comment: I'll take another look at this DISTINCT statement, seems like this will solve my problem.

Comment: This was definitely a cleaner example, yet it didn't accomplish what @coge.soft had done. I appreciate your help, though :)

Comment: your query doesn't work.  here's the sqlfiddle:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16332/5/0

Comment: @coge.soft Yes I made a mistake, since your query works I've deleted mine. However for reasons of performance making two SELECT could be a problem when there are a lot of datas ? Using a group by as funtine suggest is better I think.